# Use Java source dirs from ant build.xml to configure Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I have an existing Java project with an ant `build.xml` and I'm trying to use Netbeans as my IDE.

In Netbeans I've created a new *Java Free-Form Project* and pointed it at my ant file. This works fine for building, running, etc. However code completion does not work unless I manually add all the java sources for my project (that are already defined in my own `build.xml`!) via the Netbeans project properties "Java Sources" tab. This is very tedius because this project has has many source dirs.

Is there a way to get Netbeans to recognize the source dirs that are already defined in my ant `build.xml` to get functionality like autocomplete working?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? What version of NetBeans were you using?

Comment: No. I switched our build system to Maven. Works extremely well with Netbeans (I'm using v7.2). I can confidently run the build from the command line (and Jenkins) or Netbeans and guarantee the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans stores the project information in project.xml file not to modify build.xml.

You can set code completion for your case. For this:

- do right click on your project and select ‘Properties’

- click on ‘Java Source Classpath’ in ‘Categories’ panel

- check ‘Separate Classpath for Each Source Package Folder’

If you want to add new source folder select ‘Java Source’ in ‘Categories’ panel and then click on button ‘Add Folder...’

Comment: Thankyou, but I'm trying to avoid doing that (because it violates DRY).